# stripe.Subscription.create - Subscription attribute is not available

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am importing stripe==1.75.0 which is installed via pip.

I got "**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Subscription'**" error when I was calling it like that:

```
            try:
            subscribe = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=customer.id,
                items=[
                    {
                        "plan": plan_id,
                    },
                ]
            )
```

All the other attributes are working fine like stripe.Customer.create or stripe.Charge.create etc.

Here are all the available methods:
[image: Available Modules]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I just tested with Stripe 1.75.0, and I have no such problem... `stripe.Subscription.create` works like a charm... Are you using Python 2 or 3 ? But I don't think it makes a difference anyway.

Comment: I checked - everything works fine. Could you please show us your import statment?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

I just do "import stripe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `stripe` module being imported is likely an older version. Can you check the value of `stripe.VERSION`?

I'd recommend reinstalling the `stripe` module, e.g. via `pip uninstall stripe` then `pip install --upgrade stripe`. If you're using a virtual environment, make sure that you've activated it before running the `pip` commands.

Comment:  python                                                                                                                                             
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2

>>> import stripe
>>> print (stripe.VERSION)
1.9.2

Comment: I just did upgrade and it pulled me down to version 1.77.1 and now it's there. Weird. Thank you for the fix.                    
>>> import stripe
>>> print (stripe.VERSION)
1.77.1

Comment: I think it actually was an upgrade. Your previous version was 1.9.2, not  1.90.2. And 77 is greater than 9.